# How to click on a javascript button in htmlunit

Tags: java, javascript, html, htmlunit

I'm trying to click on a search button in this website:

http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/portals/trek/default.aspx?Culture=en-US

The button is in here somewhere

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="QuickSearchFormFlightModuleButtonsTable"
                width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="cell1">
                        <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_hlFlightDetailedSearch" href="javascript:if(typeof notRedirectToTop == 'undefined'){document.forms[0].target = '_top';}__doPostBack('ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_hlFlightDetailedSearch', '');">Advanced options</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cell2">
                    </td>
                    <td class="cell3">

                    </td>
                    <td class="cell4">
                    </td>
                    <td class="cell5">
                        <script>DumpButtonHTML('ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch','QuickSearchModuleFlightSearchStartSearchButton','QuickSearchModuleFlightSearchStartSearch','javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$QuickSearchAll1$QuickFlightSearchControl1$ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch_LinkButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, true));LockButton(this,\'\',true);Loading(IsValidForTableButton(\'\',true),\'DefaultSplash_SplashScreen\',\'/trek/App_Themes/trek_theme1/Templates/SplashScreens/\',\'ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtSearch_txtFrom;ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtSearch_txtTo;ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtDepartureDate_txtDate;ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtReturnDate_txtDate\');','True','Search','100px','True','','trek_theme1');</script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The button is the search button on the left side of the site. I used HtmlUnitScripter add-on for firefox for generating a class but even though it generates the code that will fill the forms it doesn't generate the code that will click the button.

After the button is pressed, there is a loading screen and then the results are displayed. Normally this next code should return the results page into the `page` variable

```
HtmlElement theElement5 = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch");
page = (HtmlPage) theElement5.click();
```

But it only returns the previous page with the forms filled. Is there a special way to handle this button or am I not finding the right button to click? Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

The exception I get when I used

```
ScriptResult result = page.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch_Table').onclick()");
final Page newPage = result.getNewPage();
```

is below

```
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[64] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/Amadeus/js/Functions.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property "cancelBubble" from undefined (http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/Amadeus/js/Functions.js#64)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "cancelBubble" from undefined (http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/Amadeus/js/Functions.js#64)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:530)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:979)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:947)
at htmlunittest.test.com.TestEkoBilet.main(TestEkoBilet.java:51)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "cancelBubble" from undefined (http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/Amadeus/js/Functions.js#64)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectPropNoWarn(ScriptRuntime.java:1488)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1233)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventHandler.call(EventHandler.java:81)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1531)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
... 7 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "cancelBubble" from undefined (http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/Amadeus/js/Functions.js#64)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3608)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3624)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectPropNoWarn(ScriptRuntime.java:1488)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1233)
at script.StopEvent(http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/Amadeus/js/Functions.js:64)
at script.onclick(onclick event for HtmlTable[<table id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch_Table" onmouseout="this.className='QuickSearchModuleFlightSearchStartSearchButton';" border="0" width="100px" class="QuickSearchModuleFlightSearchStartSearchButton" cellpadding="0" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$cph1$cph1$QuickSearchAll1$QuickFlightSearchControl1$ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch_LinkButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, true));LockButton(this,'',true);Loading(IsValidForTableButton('',true),'DefaultSplash_SplashScreen','/trek/App_Themes/trek_theme1/Templates/SplashScreens/','ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtSearch_txtFrom;ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtSearch_txtTo;ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtDepartureDate_txtDate;ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtReturnDate_txtDate');StopEvent(event);" onmouseover="this.className='QuickSearchModuleFlightSearchStartSearchButtonOver';" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;" cellspacing="0">] in http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/portals/trek/default.aspx?Culture=en-US)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventHandler.call(EventHandler.java:81)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1531)
at script(injected script:1)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:275)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3031)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:546)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:654)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:555)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:530)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:979)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScript(HtmlPage.java:947)
at htmlunittest.test.com.TestEkoBilet.main(TestEkoBilet.java:51)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

I think it is trying to access some other script in the site but it's not on the current page. Can htmlunit still access those scripts via some function or is this as far as it gets?

EDIT 2:

I found the following script near the beginning of the page. Does that have anything to do with the search button? It seems to have the id of the button but I'm not sure.

```
</script>
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="default.aspx?Culture=en-US" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch')" id="aspnetForm">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="__WPPS" id="__WPPS" value="s"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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"/>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Wow. Still no answer? Is the question unclear or is there no solution for this?

Comment: I edited the post and added the exception log from running the executeJavaScript method. Is the script trying to access some other script? or am I missing some obvious point?

Answer (score 7):

try this if you are unable to click on the button

```
   HtmlElement htmlElement = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch_Table\"]/tbody/tr/td[2]");
   htmlElement.click();
```

if this is not what you are looking for, and you already handled the click part
i suggest try wait for the page and javascript to load and execute.

**try this**

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
```

**or**

```
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.setAjaxController(new AjaxController(){
@Override
public boolean processSynchron(HtmlPage page, WebRequest request, boolean async)
{
return true;
}
});
```

**or**

```
JavaScriptJobManager manager = page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
while (manager.getJobCount() > 0) {
Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The click function is in the table element, try this(didn't try on my own):

```
HtmlElement theElement5 = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch_Table");
page = (HtmlPage) theElement5.click();
```

is this don't work, you can enable log on debug level to se whats happening, or try this(works on FF):

```
ScriptResult result = page.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch_Table').onclick()");
final Page newPage = result.getNewPage();
```

Hint: use Firebug to check the page variables and elements, and page.asXml() to get the real state of the page.

Comment: The first one still returns the old page. The second one is throwing an exception and terminating. I added the exception log in the question.

Comment: also can it be because the site is actually going to a loading screen first and then displaying the results?