# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using HtmlunitDriver/Phantomjs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am using HTMLUnitDriver. It is unable to locate the xpaths and css selectors

```
WebDriver d=new HtmlUnitDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
// d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
d.get("http://www.google.com");
//d.manage().window().maximize();
d.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("flipkart");
d.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
String s1 = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rhs_block']/ol/li/div[1]/div/div[1]/ol/li[2]/div/div[1]"))).getText();
//String s1=d.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.kno-ecr-pt.kno-fb-ctx")).
Assert.assertEquals(s1,"Flipkart");
System.out.println(s1);
d.close();
d.quit();
```

It works Fine with all browser but not HTMLUNITDRIVER

I read some posts saying that we need to give wait I tried with all the possible waits in selenium.

I have tried with PhantomJS, but with the same issue of Unable to locate xpath.

```
File file = new File("C:/jars/phantomjs-2.0.0-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");             
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());        
WebDriver d = new PhantomJSDriver(); 

//WebDriver d=new HtmlUnitDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
d.get("http://www.google.com");
//  d.manage().window().maximize();
d.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("flipkart");
d.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
String s1 = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rhs_block']/ol/li/div[1]/div/div[1]/ol/li[2]/div/div[1]"))).getText();
//String s1=d.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.kno-ecr-pt.kno-fb-ctx")).
Assert.assertEquals(s1,"Flipkart");
System.out.println(s1);
d.close();
d.quit();
```

Comment: HtmlUnitDriver is a fake browser, which can't handle javascript and lacks of features which normal browsers have.

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot of the page to see if you're even on the correct page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it the problem was with the jar i was using the jar phantomjsdriver-1.1.0.jar i have changed the versions of jar now which is phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar works perfectly fine.

Thanks for the help friends.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the display size of HTMLUnit and PhantomJS, by default, will render the mobile version of a page, if it exists.  You can work around this by setting the display size of the driver explicitly:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1200));
```

where 1920 would be the window width in pixels, and 1200 is the window height in pixels.  Set them to whatever you think is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnitDriver might have problems with some websites. Another option for you might be to use PhantomJS. [**Here's a discussion about the differences between them**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008825/htmlunitdriver-htmlunit-vs-ghostdriver-phantomjs).

Comment: i am using phantom js i don't no where i am committing mistakes does it recognizes  xpaths ? id and name works fine but not xpath or css selectors

Answer (score 1):

When we use HtmlUnitDriver, we are not getting rhs block(flipkart info section which appears on right hand side). I tried to get page source(htmlunitdriver) and found that it does not contain html markup for rhs block. The same is coming when we use firefox driver.

Might be that rhs block requires some physical browser support to display.(MAY BE, JUST ASSUMPTION).

So, since it is not coming, you are getting **NoSuchElementException** for HtmlUnitDriver.

Comment: yes i got the solution for was not on the write screen i maximized the window and tried for some other application its working fine nw