# phantomjs doesnt work with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

i am using Selenium 2.44.0 and PhantomJS 1.9.8. My code:

```
DesiredCapabilities c = new DesiredCapabilities();
c.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "<url to phantomjs.exe>");
WebDriver w = new PhantomJSDriver(c);
```

Error:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies

What should I do?

Comment: properly formatted code and error

Comment: Have you tried PhantomJS 2.1.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium 2.44.0 is pretty old now ([October 2014](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-2.44.0)), and PhantomJS 1.9.x is also [pretty well obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273077/954442).

However, the 2.44.0 / PhantomJS incompatibility is quite well documented:

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/8088
https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/397

And the [solution was provided in 2.45.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/18495c0b556e938966908280511a54f5e12dd3f9) with an updated PhantomJS driver (i.e. Selenium Java code, no change to the application).

So all you *actually* need to do is upgrade to 2.45.0.