# PhantomJS incompatible to HTML5 and CSS3 web technology

Tags: python-2.7

When tried getting the URL with webdriver (PhantomJS) getting incompatible browser error? Anyone experienced or have solution to it?

Thanks

Comment: What version of PhantomJS are you using? There seem to be [many issues with versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988363/phantomjs-doesnt-work-with-selenium-java)

Comment: **PhantomJS 2.0.0** ; But i tried with request, beautifulsoup, mechanize module, still the same error.

Comment: https://www.esios.ree.es/en - This is the website i am trying to get hold off