# Enabling javascript when interacting with Selenium to Google Translate website fails

Tags: java, selenium, exception, webdriver

I'm trying to interact with Selenium to Google Translate Website.

If I run the following code all works fine, but in the constructor if I want to enable the javascript it goes in exception. I searched for one hour in google but nothing helped me.

This works:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("https://translate.google.it/");
```

This doesn't works:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
driver.get("https://translate.google.it/");
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot delete property "1" of undefined (https://translate.google.it/translate/releases/twsfe_w_20160822_RC00/r/js/desktop_module_main.js#16)
```

I think the problem is related to google translate website, because in another website it works, but I don't know how to "repair" this exception.

Can you help me please?
Thanks Davide

Answer (score 0):

It could be problem of htmlunit rhino engine. 
Maybe make sense to switch to PhantomJS? 
[HtmlUnitDriver (HtmlUnit) vs GhostDriver (PhantomJS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008825/htmlunitdriver-htmlunit-vs-ghostdriver-phantomjs)