# Timeout exception with Selenium in Headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, vds

I create driver by:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='down/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
```

After using:

```
driver.get('https://myip.ru/')
r=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ipcontent"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td'))).text
print(r)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "twitter.py", line 220, in main
    r=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ipcontent"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td'))).text
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

But it works fine without headless mode

I am also trying to start it on vds and use proxy login by ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got an answer but I found this: `options.add_argument("--headless=new")`
and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but the headless option is with **--headless**, you forgot the **--** part.

Comment: it works both ways :)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
    r=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ipcontent"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td'))).text
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message
```

...implies that *TimeoutException* was raised while searching for the element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the *visibility of the element* with the following [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) based [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
//*[@id="ipcontent"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td
```

This phenomenon can be occassionally observed when the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) is loaded [differently in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099311/7429447).

You may like to construct a more canonical [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447) which identifies the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447) uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and should be a seperate discussion all together.